# How do you assign numbers to unique strings in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

By this I mean...
Let's say you have cell values of the following under

```
column1
1. Sedan
2. Trucks
3. SUV
4. SportsCar
```

What I want to do is create a query that inserts a value of 1 to Sedan, Trucks, SUV, etc.. (Four cell values are just given as an example, I need to do this for hundreds of rows.)

It would look something like this after:

```
1. Sedan1
2. Trucks2
3. SUV3
4. SportsCar4
```

Would this even be possible?

Comment: mysql or sql server? Please don't tag products not involved

Comment: Also, why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Agree with the previous comment, you might be doing this to solve another problem but you might not need to do it this way to solve it.  Given that, can you use Row_Number() and just concatenate it?  Is there some method to how you want to apply the numbers?

Comment: Thanks, I am new to sql so I was not sure which products to tag. Will keep this in mind next time. I'm always up for a better way to do it if there is.

Comment: I was in the process of editing it. I am new to both stackoverflow and sql so my apologies.

Comment: I didn't expect these answers to come in so fast. Haha.

Comment: You got your answers. For next time, though, SO is not (in general, though some users are kind :P) a code writing service. It's appreciated if you show what you've tried yourself, and what problems you've encountered.

Comment: Finally, I guess you meant to say "cell values of the following order". This is not the case, rows in a table in a relational database do not have an inherent order, the only order that's guaranteed is if you `select` with an `order by` clause. Hence, the answers below won't give the exact output you request.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server

```
with Products as
(
select product, row_number() over(order by a_column) as R_ord
from mytable
)
update Products 
set product = product + cast(R_ord as varchar(50))
```

Also, why? Why not use a table to do this?

Comment: `Row_Number` returns `BIGINT` you have to do a explicit conversion to `varchar`. `product + cast(R_ord as varchar(50))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying to change the cell values in an already existing table. If I already have the table, what would be the better way to do it?

Comment: @Prdp I thought this would handle as an implicit conversion, but I've added for completeness

Comment: `Concat` function does implicit conversion but unfortunately question is tagged with `2008`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #b
    ([column1] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO #b
    ([column1])
VALUES
    ('Sedan'),
    ('Trucks'),
    ('SUV'),
    ('SportsCar')
;

with Products as
(
select [column1], row_number() over(order by [column1]) as upd
from #b
)

select  [column1] =  [column1] + cast(upd as varchar(50)) from products
```

output

```
column1
Sedan1
SportsCar2
SUV3
Trucks4
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to concatenate the value with a cast on the row_number function.  But as mentioned before, not sure why you'd want to do this.

```
select top 10 
column1 + cast(row_number() over (order by column1 ) as varchar(10)) 
from my table
```

Comment: Site won't let me post answers with formatted code.  I've even tried posting and then editing but it fails.  I've searched on Meta and it happens to others but not commonly enough to be fixed.  Also it might be some kind of blocker on my side.  Not sure.  Seems to work sometimes but not others.

Comment: I edited it and you changed it back... now JohnHC edited it again for you. Use the format code button or back ticks located above the tab key --> `

Comment: thanks for the play by play.  I tried again to edit but it failed.